# Compare string with with 2 strings simultaniously in JS

Tags: javascript, if-statement, compare

Why is this not working in JavaScript? I'm fairly new to programming.

```
var material = 'wood';

if (material != ('alu'||'plastic')) {
    material = 'plastic';
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because `||` operator in javascript doesn't work like this.

Answer (score 4):

You could use Array's methods such as [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
if (['alu','plastic'].indexOf(material) >= 0) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You instead need something like this:

```
if (material != 'alu' && material != 'plastic')
```

This is because the `||` operator requires an expression on both sides, meaning that you need to do a comparison on both sides.

EDIT: I changed it to `&&` because I realized you wanted if check if the material was *neither* of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular expression:

```
var material = 'wood';

if (!/^(.*?(\balu\b|\b plastic\b)[^$]*)$/.test(material)) {
    material = 'plastic';
}
```